# jQueryUI - "invalid label" error in console

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Getting a JS error when I load the following script:

```
    // increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).live('dialog',function() {
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });

    $( "#opener" ).live('click',function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is the console error:

```
invalid label - [Break on this error] show: 'blind',\n
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Think about this for a bit. You're declared an anonymous function on line four, but instead of a normal function body you wrote a js object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to put the values into a function. They are properties of the dialog box directly.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });

    $( "#opener" ).live('click',function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });
});
```

See the [jQuery UI Dialog documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated) for more details. (There is an example of an animated dialog as well.)

Comment: whoops, went a little crazy there with live()

Comment: JasCav, I'm getting the message now "uncaught exception: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization" in firebug console. A search didn't reveal much information about that. Any ideas?

Comment: 15 Minutes of fiddling with object names and value construction and this answer tipped me off that my nesting was borked. Thanks!